# How get `this` from action in react redux app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        isLogin: false
    }

    render() {
        <div>
            <h1>{isLogin "Logined" : "Not logged" }</h1>
            <button onClick={this.props.handleLogin}>Login</button>
        </div>
    }
}

export default connect(
    state => ({
        user: state.user
    }),

    dispatch => ({
        handleLogin: e => {
            typeof this // "undefined"
            this.setState({isLogin: true});
            dispatch('LOGIN');
        }
    })
)(App);
```

I need to call `this.setState(...);`
I use this method getting `this` from Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        isLogin: false
    }

    render() {
        <div>
            <h1>{isLogin "Logined" : "Not logged" }</h1>
            <button onClick={this.props.handleLogin(this)}>Login</button>
        </div>
    }
}

export default connect(
    state => ({
        user: state.user
    }),

    dispatch => ({
        handleLogin: _this => e => {
            _this.setState({isLogin: true});
            dispatch('LOGIN');
        }
    })
)(App);
```

I do not consider this decision to be true.
How to do it right?

Comment: Why would you setState in action ? if you're using redux

Comment: Since you are using redux, you should just modify the state in the redux store.

Comment: I understand what to do in a reducer. This is just an example of getting `this`

Comment: @BorodinDK You don't need to get `this` if you write the action and reducer correctly.

Comment: What u want to do with this here?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of using redux is to have a "global" state in the store. An action creator returns an object which is dispatched to a reducer that then returns the updated state. Thunk allows you to delay evaluation of the action object.

Putting this all together, you can do something like this:

```
export default connect(
    state => ({
        user: state.user,
        isLogin: state.isLogin,
    }),

    dispatch => ({
        handleLogin: e => {
            dispatch('LOGIN');
        }
    })
)(App);
```

Now you need a reducer that determines what to do with the `'LOGIN'` action:

```
reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action) {
        case 'LOGIN':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {isLogin: true});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your stet inside the component and then call the prop.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        isLogin: false
    }
    handleLogin = () => {
      this.setState({ isLogin: true })
      this.props.handleLogin()
    };
    render() {
        <div>
            <h1>{isLogin "Logined" : "Not logged" }</h1>
            <button onClick={this.handleLogin}>Login</button>
        </div>
    }
}

export default connect(
    state => ({
        user: state.user
    }),

    dispatch => ({
        handleLogin: e => {
            dispatch('LOGIN');
        }
    })
)(App);
```

in a Realword example, you should set a loggedIn flag in your Redux store, not in your Component.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access this.setState from outside App components context.

If I understand you correctly, you want check if you are logged in inside component.

I suggest to have a property in state.user which is called something like: *isAuthenticated* and use that for your logic instead.

```
this.props.user.isAuthenticated ? 'logged in' : 'not logged in'
```

Alternatively you could call an function which does both changes inside context.

*jsx*

```
onClick={() => this.myOnClick()}
```

*component*

```
myOnClick = () => {
  this.setState({isLogin: true}); 
  this.props.handleLogin(); 
}
```

A bit unclear what you are trying to do though:)